# Array out of bounds exception despite loop condition being correct

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

In the following code binchar is a char array having 98 elements and nv22 is an integer variable which has a different random value every time the program runs. The problem is it always gives me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :98 at the line
ar[nv22-17]=binchar[l];
the while loop states l

```
System.out.println("Enter a message");
Scanner ss= new Scanner(System.in);
String s=ss.nextLine();
char[] ar=s.toCharArray();

len=ar.length;
int l=0;

while(l<len)
{
    for(int y=0; y<25; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0;x<20; x++)
        {
            ar[nv22-17]=binchar[l];
            l++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is ar[nv22-17] and what is arr.length

Comment: Please add information about the size of `binchar` and check if `nv22-17` is ALWAYS  inside [0, ar.length-1].

Comment: ar is the character array. i have stored the string as a character array. ar.length is the length of the character array @JigarJoshi

Comment: @StefanFreitag binchar has length 98 i.e binchar[0] to binchar[97].

Comment: @StefanFreitag yes it is always indside the limit

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code:

```
for(int y=0; y<25; y++)
{
    for (int x=0;x<20; x++)
    {
        ar[nv22-17]=binchar[l];
        l++;
    }
}
```

Outer `for` loop will loop 25 times, inner `for` loop 20 times. inside inner `for` loop you increment `l++` for each loop, which up to `500`, while `binchar` size is only `98`.

means you are trying to access `binchar[98]` (until `500`) which definitely throws `arraysindexoutofbound`

Comment: @Manika just remove both of your `for` loop

Comment: then how do increment the variables x and y if i remove the loops

Comment: of course you have to remove `x` and `y` as well. you didn't use it either

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're doing anything to insure that nv22-17 >ar.length. It's not possible to tell, but you may not be checking that 0<=nv22-17 either.

Answer (score 0):

You got array out of index because your array wont get index value which is provided by you so
Instead of while loop use for loop in which loop continue till your array lenght i.e. `len=ar.length` so syntax is like `for (int 1=0;i<len; i++)`